# Can't access Heroku console with app name

Tags: heroku, console

I just started a new app and I was able to push it to Heroku, But I it seems, that I can't access the console.

The command, that I am running is:

```
heroku run console --app myappname
```

What I get, is:

```
Running `console` attached to terminal... up, run.3951 Usage:   rails
new APP_PATH [options]

Options:   -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of
your choice
                                 # Default: /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby   -b, [--builder=BUILDER]        #
Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)   -m,
[--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a
filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
      [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install   -G, [--skip-git]               # Skip Git ignores and keeps   -O,
[--skip-active-record]     # Skip Active Record files   -S,
[--skip-sprockets]         # Skip Sprockets files   -d,
[--database=DATABASE]      # Preconfigure for selected database
(options:
mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                 # Default: sqlite3   -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]  # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript
library
                                 # Default: jquery   -J, [--skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev]                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge]                   # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository   -T, [--skip-test-unit]         # Skip
Test::Unit files
      [--old-style-hash]         # Force using old style hash (:foo =    'bar') on Ruby >= 1.9

Runtime options:   -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already
exist   -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes   -q,
[--quiet]    # Suppress status output   -s, [--skip]     # Skip files
that already exist

Rails options:   -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit  
-v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

I know, that the application name is correct, as I just pushed it and it is loaded.

When I look at the logs on Heroku for the moment, when I tried to hit the console, I see following:

```
2013-07-01T16:21:58.780979+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails console` by mzaragoza@myemail.com
2013-07-01T16:22:09.000482+00:00 heroku[run.2993]: Awaiting client
2013-07-01T16:22:09.055474+00:00 heroku[run.2993]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails console`
2013-07-01T16:22:10.342966+00:00 heroku[run.2993]: State changed from starting to up
2013-07-01T16:22:13.870963+00:00 heroku[run.2993]: Process exited with status 0
2013-07-01T16:22:13.889703+00:00 heroku[run.2993]: State changed from up to complete
```

Comment: what's wrong with that output? i don't understand what the error is

Comment: the problem is that the console does not load

Comment: "does not load" means nothing to me. is there an error? what have you tried? do other commands work? does it work with other apps? what are you expecting to see?

Comment: I can run heroku run console --app myotherapp and it loads the console. but for this new app i just get some help screen.

I can push to heroku and i can run migrations, i can even run other rake task like seed. i just cant seem to be able to access the console.

Comment: what if you do `heroku run bash` ?

Comment: heroku run bash -a myappname
it looks like i have no problem running bash. i do appreciate the help.
i just don't know where to start debugging

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but what does `console` do that you couldn't do from your `bash` shell? Couldn't you open your console from there?

Comment: i am not sure i am so use to use the console and i don't really use bash. i guess that i should start learning bash. its always good to learn

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about `heroku run rails c`? Does it make any difference if you add `rails`?

PS: I'm unsure if you want to access Rails' console or just a normal shell, from the comments.

Comment: To expand on aledalgrande's answer, you can run `heroku run rails c` when you are in the root directory of your project to open the Rails console.  To run a particular rake task, run `heroku run rake db:migrate` or whatever rake task you want to run.

Comment: "$rails c" means rails console.  To run a particular Heroku task, start with "heroku run".  Just make sure you're logged into Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

The correct form is => `heroku run "any rails command here"`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I upgraded to Rails > 4.0.0. The solution is to run locally the following command `rake rails:update:bin`. This will generate a bin directory in the root of your application. **Make sure that it is not in your `.gitignore` file**. Commit and then push the changes to Heroku.

Comment: Thanks for this, @r4m  I just built a new app from the rails_apps_composer and it included `/bin/*` in the .gitignore by default.  This caused problems with Heroku finding the right binstub.

Answer (score 0):

For 3.2.x apps:

This also just happened to me when I removed `script/rails` from my repo and pushed to Heroku. Reverting the commit and pushing that change made things work again.